# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): I can't getting my site from some machines

Tags: php

I have a site Test.com.

It can access without any problem from  some machine.

But  in from some other machine (on other network)it is not getting .
It  returning an error

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):

Can any one tell me the reason please

Comment: "It can access without…" It can access what?

Comment: `test.com` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a Chrome bug.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=19043fff689eff09&hl=en

But Thilo is right. Start accepting more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework? this might also have something to do with it. I am using codeigniter with compressed set to true. This uses the codeigniter compression algorithm to compress output, so you have to use its own output function to print something

```
(e.g. $this->output->set_content_type(...)->append_output(...))
```

hopefully this will help.